# Am I Not Posting Data Correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am not sure if I am posting multiple partial pages correctly from my ASP.NET MVC application.

On my site, I load a number of partial pages and display them in jQuery UI tabs. Here is an example of how that looks in my *Index.aspx* page (contrived example):

```
<div id="tabScenario"><% Html.RenderPartial("Scenario", Model); %></div>
<div id="tabPerson"><% Html.RenderPartial("Person", Model.People.FirstOrDefault()); %></div>
<div id="tabAddress"><% Html.RenderPartial("Address", Model.People.FirstOrDefault().Addresses.FirstOrDefault()); %></div>
```

My partial views are all strongly-typed to the singular version of each of those objects (Scenario, Person, and Address in this case).

The user enters the data he or she wants to change and then saves the data. When I post that data, I am doing this in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Header("Setup Scenario")]
public ActionResult Index(Scenario scenario, Person person, Address address, string submitButton)
{
    // Update the scenario with all the information that belongs to it.
    scenario.Person = person;
    scenario.Person.Address = address;

    // Determine whether to just save or to save and submit.
    switch (submitButton)
    {
        case "Save":
            return Save(scenario, true);
        case "Save As...":
            return Save(scenario, false);
        case "Submit":
            return Submit(scenario);
        default:
            return View();
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how correct this is because, when I go to display the information I just posted on the next view, I am receiving the following runtime error on line:

```
<div id="tabPerson"><% Html.RenderPartial("Person", Model.People.FirstOrDefault()); %></div>
```

Error:

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'Mdt.ScenarioDBModels.Scenario', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'Mdt.ScenarioDBModels.Person'.

What confuses me is that, if you look at the particular line, I am getting Person. So, based off of this post, it tells me my value is most likely null and ASP.NET is "falling back" to the Scenario object.

Because of all this, I figured I am doing something incorrect in how I am posting all my data (there is a lot of it), but I am stuck at what that would be.

**Clarifications**

I am posting via Ajax. Here is the BeginForm statement.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Scenario", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "scenarioSubmitSuccess" }, new { id = "scenarioForm" }))
{ %>
   // My Index.aspx
<% } %>
```

The Save method is, basically, trying to save the model to the backing store (a database in this case). Here is the method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Save a the scenario.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scenario">The scenario to save to the database.</param>
    /// <param name="overwrite">True if the existing scenario should be updated in the database.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private ActionResult Save(Scenario scenario, bool overwrite)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && TryUpdateModel(scenario, "Scenario"))
        {
            ScenarioDBEntities entities = ObjectContextFactory.GetScenarioDBEntities();
            ScenarioRepository scenarioRepository = new ScenarioRepository(entities);

            if (overwrite)
            {
                scenarioRepository.Update(scenario);
            }
            else
            {
                scenarioRepository.Add(scenario);
            }

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(scenario);
    }
```

Comment: Things you need to clarify: how are you posting to the Index controller action (AJAX, form, something else)? What is the `Save` action doing? What model does it pass to the view?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Updated with the information.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - I updated my post to show how I am building a Scenario via the Action method (after the Post). All that data is technically part of the scenario...it just makes sense to split it up from a data point of view since there is so much different data. (My example is a bit contrived - I don't show everything.) When I save, I am saving just the scenario (which now should contain all the data information). Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I wasn't updating the model properly. The answer can be found here: [Why does updating an object only work one particular way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731348/why-does-updating-an-object-only-work-one-particular-way)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `Save` method you are always passing `scenario` as view model, no matter in which context this method has been invoked (scenario, person or address):

```
return View(scenario);
```

while your `Person.ascx` partial expects `Person` as view model. So you need to pass the person to the view in case you are trying to update the person partial.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused by your answer. I thought I was only calling "Save" on the scenario because I was trying to save everything together (AKA, if I update the Scenario, I update everything in the backing store). How would I pass individual parts? (I apologize if this is a dumb follow-up question...I'm just not sure I get what you're saying.)